# Webpack build command is not outputting build directory when running docker build

Tags: docker, webpack

Why is my '/build' folder not present in my docker container, but is present when I run yarn build locally?
Could there be a problem with the path dependency at the top of webpack.prod.config.ts? Where the container cannot resolve the path but my machine can? Should I be working with a different host container?

Thanks for the help in advance!

### Error

> ERROR [4/4] COPY --from=build /app/build .                                                        0.0s
> [click-n-file 4/4] COPY --from=build /app/build .:
> failed to compute cache key: "/app/build" not found: not found

### Files

Dockerfile

```
# Multi-stage Docker file
#  1) Build the node project with the latest version of node
#  2) NGNIX to serve the production front end packed via webpack

# Stage 1: Building the application
FROM node:latest AS build

WORKDIR /app

# Copy the app to the working directory on the image
COPY . .

# Install node modules and build application
RUN yarn install && yarn run build

# Stage 2: Serve content using NGINX Web Server
FROM nginx:latest

ENV NODE_ENV production

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
# Remove default nginx static assets
RUN rm -rf ./*
# Copy static assets from builder stage
COPY --from=build /app/build .

# Containers run nginx with global directives and daemon off
ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

webpack.prod.config.ts

```js
import path from 'path'
import { Configuration } from 'webpack'
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin'
import ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin from 'fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin'
import ESLintPlugin from 'eslint-webpack-plugin'
import { CleanWebpackPlugin } from 'clean-webpack-plugin'
import tailwindcss from 'tailwindcss'
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer'
import CssMinimizerPlugin from 'css-minimizer-webpack-plugin'

const config: Configuration = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './src/index.tsx',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/i,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              '@babel/preset-env',
              '@babel/preset-react',
              '@babel/preset-typescript',
            ],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/i,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              sassOptions: {
                // https://github.com/sass/node-sass#outputstyle
                outputStyle: 'compressed',
              },
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader', // postcss loader needed for tailwindcss
            options: {
              postcssOptions: {
                ident: 'postcss',
                plugins: [tailwindcss, autoprefixer],
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'public/index.html',
    }),

    new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
      async: false,
    }),

    new ESLintPlugin({
      extensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx'],
    }),

    // The CleanWebpackPlugin plugin will clear out the build folder.
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
  ],
  performance: {
    hints: false,
    maxEntrypointSize: 512000,
    maxAssetSize: 512000,
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      // For webpack@5 you can use the `...` syntax to extend existing minimizers
      '...',
      new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
    ],
  },
};

export default config
```

package.json

```json
"scripts": {
    ...
    "build": "webpack --config webpack/webpack.prod.config.ts",
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the 'best' answer but I just added the output-directory in the NPM script

```json
"scripts": {
    ...
    "build": "webpack --config webpack/webpack.prod.config.ts -o ./build",
    ...
}
```

And that fixed my problem!